# Confusion about units of physical magnitudes in the Hamiltonian of the Ising model

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, ferromagnetism

I am having trouble with the units used in the Hamiltonian of the Ising model. I have search several notes, I have three examples in the picture below

No one states explicitly what the units of the following terms are: $S_i, J$ and  $ H,B,h$ (these should all represent a magnetic field :)

1. Do the spin variables $S_i$ have dimensions or not, they just say they can have values $+-1$? I guess they are dimensionless.
2. If that is true, since most call $J$ an energy interaction factor, I guess $ J$ must have units of energy as the hamiltonian does, so that $-\sum_i JS_iS_j$ can have units of energy
3. What about the units of $H, B$ or $h$? They say they represent magnetic field, but how can that be, if considering $S_i$ is dimensionless, $hS_i$ or $BS_i$ or $HS_i$ all have  units of magnetic field, when they should instead have units of energy. I feel like a magnetic moment $\mu$ factor is missing there, unless for some unknown reason it has been secretly set to 1 and no one talks about it.
   In fact  before learning about the Ising model, when I studied the canonical ensamble, my professor used $-\sum_i S_iB\mu$ for the energy of  interaction ot the spins with the magnetic field, that looked ok, but when we did the Ising model he joined the secret club and dropped that $\mu$ factor as well.
4. Supposing $H, B$ or $h$ are magnetic field, and that the  natural and correct way of writting this last term is $-\mu B \sum_i S_i $. Different people use this letters indifferently without adding any extra factor, but   shouldn't a magnetic permeability factor be missing if I used $H$ or $h$  instead of $B$?. I recall from electromagnetism that $B=\tilde \mu H$ ( where  I am using $\tilde \mu$ for the magnetic permeability to distinguish it from the magnetic moment $\mu$) and that the energy of a magnetic dipole is $-\mu B$. So, if I were to use $H$, I guess I should write  $- \mu B\sum_i\  S_i  = - \mu (\tilde\mu H )\sum_i\  S_i  $instead of just $-H \sum_i S_i $ or $-\mu H \sum_i S_i $, shouldn't I?

How do I make sense of all this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are dimensionless units. In principle one could start with a dimensional Hamiltonian and define the dimensionless units, e.g., the Zeeman term of a spin coupled to a magnetic field is
$$
H_Z = -\frac{g\mu_B}{\hbar}\mathbf{S}\cdot\mathbf{B},
$$
assuming the quantization axis along the magnetic field, we can write
$$
H_Z = -\frac{g\mu_B}{\hbar}BS_z = -\frac{g\mu_B}{\hbar}B\frac{\hbar}{2}\hat{\sigma}_z = -h\hat{\sigma}_z,
$$
where $\hat{\sigma}_z$ is the Pauli matrix with eigenvalues $\pm 1$, whereas the rest of the coefficients are absorbed into constant $h$.

However, as the role of the Ising model is not in making quantitative predictions for the values of magnetization, but in providing insights into critical behavior, one is rarely concerned with actual units and the expressions for the dimensionless quantities used.

Comment: So, are you saying all $S_i, B, H $and $\mu$ are dimensionless?

Comment: Yes, indeed. What is confusing here is that these letters are often used to denote dimensional quantities. But in theoretical physics one often avoids writing and rewriting the same coefficients, like $\hbar, k_B, c, \mu_B$ etc.

Comment: For example, when studing the ensembles in statistical physics, we often had to divide by Planck's constant raised to the number of dimensions to make the partion function dimensionless, if everything is dimensionless why did we care about this ?. Besides when writting the partition function for the Ising Hamiltonian one writes the  $1/Z*exp(-\beta*H)$ If H is dimensionless, why do we always write the $\beta$ factor ?

Comment: 1. Making things dimensionless does not mean that we ignore dimensions - we either combine different quantities so that they for dimensionless constants or, at maximum, keep in mind that all the quantities have the same dimension (e.g., the Hamiltonian and the temperature).

2. In elementary physics one insists on writing all dimensional quantities as a matter of pedagogical approach. In practice however, it is inconvenient to write the same factors again and again when doing lengthy calculations. For example, you wrote $\beta$ instead of $1/(k_BT)$

Comment: 3. In your example $H$ is the system energy, $\beta$ is the inverse temperature. They are written separately, because they have different physical meaning, not just to make the system dimensionless. In critical phenomena one often studies how behavior of a system changes with temperature - i.e., $H$ remains teh same, while $\beta$ changes.

Comment: To add to this answer, note that the Ising model has **many** different interpretations: as a model of a ferromagnet, as a model of a fluid, as a model for a binary mixture, etc. Even the *interpretation* of the "spins" $S_i$ and of the parameter $h$ changes drastically, let alone their units! People studying this model are interested in its qualitative features, and usually don't care about quantitative details.

Comment: @ Yvan Velenik, While we don't care about qualitative features, still for plotting we need some coherent numerical values, don't we? In fact I am struggling with this as I have posted here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/579987/plotting-the-magnetic-susceptibility-of-the-mean-field-ising-model. Take a look if you've got a minute