# Plotting the magnetic susceptibility of the mean field Ising model

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, ferromagnetism

I am struggling to understand how they have ploted some functions regarding the Ising model in the mean field approximation (Curie-Weiss model) in my lecture notes
For more details,you can see them here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TPFsNwuuVA5uLDNyZkJRyaFdIorUC9nn/view?usp=sharing

The hamiltonian  of the model is

[image]
The magnetic susceptibility as computed from the combinatorial approach to the Curie-Weiss model yields the following expression:

[image]
where $m$ is the magnetization density which varies in $[-1,1]$ and J is the hamiltonian's energy coupling term.
and the following plot is presented:

[image]

I am trying to plot this myself. I have to express $\chi_T$ as a function of T/J. They are considering $\beta=1/T$, so:
$$\chi_T= \frac{1}{T}(1-tanh^2[\frac{h+Jm}{T})])$$
to try to make the T/J ratio show up, I do:
$$\chi_T= \frac{1}{J}\frac{1}{T/J}(1-tanh^2[\frac{h+Jm}{JT/J})])$$  and calling r=T/J:
$$\chi_T(r)= J\frac{1}{r}(1-tanh^2[\frac{h+Jm}{Jr})])$$

They have plotted this relation for $ h=0$ and $h=0.1$. The problem is that I don't know the values of $m $and $J$, and no mention of them is made in the document. Am I supposed to assign random values? If so, how do I assign coherent values?

Clueless as to what values to assign, I assigned for h=0 case:  J=1, and m=1 ,and I got:
[image]
But I am not getting the peak at $T/J=r=1$ and its corresponding value $\chi_T=1$ which is an important feature of the model

Comment: You seem to be treating $m$ as a fixed parameter, but (if I'm not misreading your question) it ought to vary with $J/T$ as well. What happens if you include this?

Comment: @catalogue_number Yes,that might be it : actually $m = tanh [β (h + Jm)]=  tanh [ (h + Jm)/T] $, but this is a transcedental equation with no closed-form solution and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @mathlover it is very easy to compute the value of $m$ numerically. Just consider the recursive sequence $m(n+1) = \tanh(\beta(h+Jm(n))$. Compute the $m(n)$ iteratively (starting from some reasonable value, say $m(0)=.5$). It will very quickly converge to the true value. For instance you can iterate it until the difference $|m(n+1)-m(n)|$ is smaller than some fixed small threshold.

Comment: For instance, the method described above is the way Figures 2.5 and 2.6 were obtained in [this book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook). Note also that I find it strange to compute $\mathrm{d}m/\mathrm{d}h$ at $h=0$ when $T<T_c$, since the function $m$ is not differentiable there (it is not even continuous!).

Comment: @ Yvan Velenik thanks I'll take a look.  Supposing we don't the plot yet, how do you know $dm/dh$ is not differentiable at $ h=0$ ?

Comment: @ Yvan Velenik ,If I follow the suggestion on the iterative solution, before even starting, I still need to assign values to J and T, don't I? How do I choose reasonable values?

Comment: As I said, the magnetization is a discontinuous function at $h=0$ when $T<T_c$: $\lim_{h\downarrow 0} m(T,h) = m^*(T)$, $\lim_{h\uparrow 0} m(T,h) = -m^*(T)$, where $m^*(T)>0$ is the spontaneous magnetization at temperature $T$.

Comment: Keeping $J,h,\beta$ as parameters is redundant: you can always rescale things so that $J=1$. So, take $J=1$ and compute $m^*(T)$ for "all" $T<T_c$ (for $T\geq T_c$, $m^*(T) =0$, so no need to compute it). Depending on what you want, do the same for nonzero values of $h$ (then, you need to consider "all" values of $T$).

Comment: Of course, if you are really interested in the critical behavior of $\chi_T$, then you can focus on a neighborhood of $T_c$ (but, then, you should rather analyze *analytically* the critical behavior: this is easy for the mean-field model).

Comment: How do I determine the value or functional expresion of $T_c$?, I just know about it qualitatively.. Sorry I still don't get how you can compute the limits of $m(T,m)$, given that we  only have the implicit equation

Comment: In the mean-field model, you can compute $T_c$ explicitly (and basically everything you want). This is done in most textbooks; see our book, Chapter 2, for instance. We also address the critical behavior.

Comment: You cannot determine an analytic expression for $m(T,h)$: the best you can hope for is the implicit equation. However, it is easy to solve the latter numerically to arbitrary accuracy. Still, you can easily prove that the magnetization is discontinuous (equivalently, that there is spontaneous magnetization) when $T<T_c$ without *explicitly* computing $m(T,h)$.